# JavaScript for loop "document.getElementById"

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Hi I am trying to go throw radio buttons using a for loop , with ID of "Group" and get the value of it show out here is my code but it doesnt alert the value of them on submit,

http://jsfiddle.net/JAwZg/

Comment: document.getElementById("someId") will give you only one element.

Comment: your id is same for the both of the input box???

Comment: I want to click on the one and tells me the value of the one, doesnt have to be same? like that is why I want to use for loop so it gives me bag the value of group[i]

Comment: like I can use this too I guess var ims = document.getElementById("group").getElementsByTagName("input")

Comment: sq2 that was perfect and exactly what I need it

Comment: it just doesnt work ON my code for some reason

Comment: There are a lot of non sense if your code, I don't see what you want to do : - You can't have many elements with the same ID, it must be unique - Your onclick event on submit button should be a onsubmit event on the form - You should use onchange event when playing with input elements - You are binding a click event on input elements AFTER the click on submit button, it's a non sense.

Comment: Do i need to add any source file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="group1" name="group" value="1" />
No Changes<br/>
<input type="radio" id="group2" name="group" value="2" />
Gray Scale <br/>
<input type="radio" id="group3" name="group" value="3" />
Old Style<br/>
<input type="radio" id="group4" name="group" value="4" />
Sharpening<br/>
```

Script:

```
var ims = document.getElementsByName("group");

for(var i = 0; i < ims.length; i++){
    ims[i].onclick = function(){alert("hi");}
}
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/JAwZg/4/

Comment: I dont know why it doesnt alert in my code still , but that is what I need thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can also do that like this.instead of ID give it a class

```
   var yourString; 

   $.each($('.className'), function(i, k){
     yourString += $(k).val()+','; 
     });
    yourString = $.trim(yourString);
    yourString = yourString.substring(0, yourString.length - 1);
```